# Stop The scratching -- what does it mean

Tags: word-usage, idiomatic-language

A person is scratching a car and now there are lots of scratches on the car. To prevent the further damage, THE scratching should be stopped.

1. Is the sentence above using "the scratching" correct?

Now you are telling the offender to stop --
"Stop the scratching".

2. Is this correct Too? Or never! and always stick to no the? Even if it seems to me I am referring to the specific scratching.
3. Stop the scratches. - is this correct too to mean scratching as in I need scratches (= I need scratching)

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you would not hear

> stop **the** scratching

as in the example you have given.

It might be used in that way if "**the scratching**" was the name of the ailment

> Your cat has scratched most of his fur off. He needs to **stop the scratching**.

However, in your example, it would usually be said

> You idiot, stop **scratching** my car!